# How to add appropriate noise to a graph

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, noise, noise-generator

I have a matlab graph. Something like a trajectory. I want to add noise to graph.
I tried adding normal distribution noise. using rand. e.g.

```
x1=x+a*rand(size(x));
```

and similarly for y.

The results are attached below. This is not what I want. This gives me a either scatter plot, or completely noisy plot. As illustrated below. The first row is what I did, third row what I want.

[image]

Different graph columns stand for different standard deviation (value of a).

Q. How to obtain third type (row) of plot?

P.S. The first row is when I use plot(...,".",markersize,1); and second row for simple vector plot.

Comment: Is it a contour? What is x? What is y? Where is the graph? Which are the nodes?

Comment: @Eleanore Yes. Coordinate. Coordinate. There are multiple definitions of a graph.[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function] not just graph with nodes and edges. But precisely, it is not graph of a function either. Let's say it's a trajectory of a particle.

Comment: This is obvious. However, you didn't specify what are x and y. Are these the coordinates of the points composing the contour? Should I suppose all the points on your plot being characterized by a coordinate (which you want to recompute)? Moreover, you didn't specify what is "noise" for you. Is it just a deformation of your contour?

Comment: @Eleanore Yes, they are points composing the contour. I don't precisely know what you mean, or what else the data could mean. But yes. what you get is right. I have position-coordinate of the particle (x,y). I plot it as (x,y) and want to recompute them. yes. and yes noise is deformation of contour.

Comment: No need to get upset :) Essentially, I am afraid adding just random noise will just mess up the points. I may suggest you to define a confidence interval around the point, since you want just to move a bit away from the original position. Something like: `coord = coord + A*rand(1)`. `A` is defined as your confidence interval: the higher `A`, the higher the noise, the larger the deformation. In this way you limit the movement of your particle, as if you are setting a leash. THis is done for both the coordinates, so as to make the particle move in the neighborhood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you want the noise to have a certain characteristic.  You have many samples along the curve, and you'd like it to stay "connected".  You'd like fairly smooth results, and you want the curve to stay closed.  So, in order: random walk noise will keep the points connected.  Low-pass-filtered noise will keep the curve smooth.  And fix the noise endpoint to be zero (smoothly) to ensure a closed result.  Here's some code that generates 16 different kinds of noise (4x4), varying the overall scale and the overall amount of filtering.  You'll have to adjust both of these choices based on the "sample rate" of your data, and the overall scale of the shape.

```
% Generate sample data
[x,y] = pol2cart(0:0.01:2*pi, 1);

% Pick a set of 4 noise scale, and noise filter values
scales = [.01 .05 .1 .5];
filterstrength = [.1 .5 .9 .98];

% Plot a 4x4 grid, picking a different type of noise for each one
for i=1:4
    for j=1:4
        scale = scales(i);
        f = filterstrength(j);

        % Generate noise for x and y, by filtering a std 1 gaussian random
        % walk
        nx = filter(scale*(1-f), [1 -f], cumsum(randn(size(x))));
        ny = filter(scale*(1-f), [1 -f], cumsum(randn(size(y))));

        % We want a closed polygon, so "detrend" the result so that
        % the last point is the same as the first point
        nx = nx - linspace(0,1,length(nx)).*(nx(end)-nx(1));
        ny = ny - linspace(0,1,length(ny)).*(ny(end)-ny(1));

        subplot(4,4,4*(i-1)+j);

        % Add the noise
        plot(x+nx,y+ny);
    end
end
```

Other things you could vary:  You have nearly infinite choices for the filter shape, which will affect the style of deformation.